# Event ID 534 logon Failure

Tags: iis, login

Cannot understand why the iuser_{machinename} is logged as in the event as logon failure: The user had not been granted the requested logon type at this machine.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue with User Rights Assignments for the anonymous access account in IIS. See the following Microsoft KB:

[Error message when you try to view a Web site that is hosted on Internet Information Server 6.0 by using anonymous access: "401.1 Unauthorized: Logon failed"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909887)

Comment: Very good. WE are checking our settings; Thank you for your comments to this question.!